# SQL insert statement with carriage return or line feed

Tags: sql

I have a question on the SQL insert statement. I am looking for a way to insert a string with a carriage return or line feed.

For example,

If I run this code:

```
insert into table (description) 
values ('this is a description' , 'Updated description.')
```

But it is not possible to do so in SQL as there will be an error.

If there is a string like:

```
This is a description. Updated description.
```

How do I insert this so that the carriage return and line feed remains?

Is there any ways to do it? Or does it need to be replaced by some system identifiable character?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. Which RDBMS-provider do you use? 2. There is no cr/lf in your question. There is a syntax error due to lack of esacape of `'` on the other hand.

Comment: Depending on RDBMS it might be something like `'Updated' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'description.'`

Comment: You are using a ' in the middle of the description.

Comment: Now you are trying to insert two values into one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert the string that you are asking for, just do:

```
insert into table (description) 
values ('This is a description. Updated description.');
```

If I have to disregard your example and guess what you are asking, it would be something like this (depending on your RDBMS-provider, which I guess is mssql):

```
insert into table (description) 
values ('This is a description.' || CHR(13)|| CHR(10) || 'Updated description.');
```

Comment: Hi, i am facing error using values ('This is a description.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Updated description.'); i am using db2 command editor to insert the statement

Comment: Db2 does not have a char function. If you had tagged your question with your actual db (in this case db2) it would be a lot easier to answer. Updated my answer.

Comment: Tried with your updated answer but both of the values are still on the same line. Updated description should be in the next line. I am using ibm db2 version 9. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like db2 uses || for concatenation, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`char(13)` is `CR`. For DOS-/Windows-style `CRLF` linebreaks, you want `char(13)+char(10)`, like:

```
'This is a description.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'Updated description.'
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
SET @text = 'This is a description.' + CHAR(13) + 'Updated description.'
SELECT @text
```

This prints out the following:

> This is a description.
>   Updated description.